# Numeric Values in xml tag

Tags: php, xml, arrays, xmlserializer

I am trying to convert array to xml data in php. I am using xmlserializer pear package for this. My array is:

```
$arr=array(1000=>'name is john');
```

When I convert it to xml using this code:

```
options=array ('mode'=>'simplexml','addDecl'=>true,'indent'=>'      ','rootName'=>'names');
$serializer = new XML_Serializer($options);
$result = $serializer->serialize($arr);
if($result == true)
                $data=$serializer->getSerializedData();
echo $data;
```

I get following response:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<names>name is john</names>
```

But I want this kind of response:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<names>
    <1000>name is john</1000>
</names>
```

can anyone tell where my mistake is?

Comment: your "desired" output is not valid XML afaik. you'd need something like `<name id="1000">...</name>`

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is because numeric values are not allowed element names in XML. However, if you really want to have "xml-style" output like above (beside it is not real xml) you must bypass the library and code it by hand. I think this will do it for you:

```
public function xml_encode($array, $tag = "root"){
    $result = '<'.$tag.'>';
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            $result.=xml_encode($value, $key);
        }else{
            $result .= '<'.$key.'>'.$value.'</'.$key.'>';
        }
    }
    $result .= '</'.$tag.'>';
    return $result;
}
```